# Should I use const char* or #define?

Tags: c, macros

I am writing a CLI tool in C and I want to print the version number if a number of places (help message, usage, etc.)

Is it best to use

```
#define VERSION "1.2.0"
```

or

```
const char *version = "1.2.0";
```

in terms of performance, compiler optimizations and so on?

Comment: `const char version[] = "1.2.0";` — it saves the space of a pointer.  Or, if you really want the pointer, `const char * const version = "1.2.0";`.

Comment: It probably won't make a difference. If you never use the address of the variable, the optimizer will generate the same code.

Comment: @John, Start with "in terms of functionality?".  Compare `sizeof(VERSION)` with `sizeof version`.  Until functionality is correct, premature optimization is not a priority.  IAC, what is _best_ is case dependent - and no use cases are shown.

Comment: I don't think this is opinion-based. In my opinion. There can be an excellent answer which covers everything. Voting to reopen.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler What about `#define VERSION "1.2.0"` followed by `const char *version = VERSION;`, or perhaps `const char version[] = VERSION;`?  There's no need to limit the possibilities to only those enumerated in the question.  ;-)

Comment: @AndrewHenle: comments are not answers — my comment was not a complete answer.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding performance, it doesn't matter for modern compilers.
For debugging, the second variant is more practical, as the debugger don't know about symbols of the preprocessor. On the other hand, if you use some way of determining the version on an application basis (for example with the GNU autotools) the first approach would be more common, as you can define it from the commandline, so you don't have to change your code, to change the version number, or let the user inject something he likes.